# FlexSlider + AngularJS error

Tags: angularjs, flexslider

```
<input ng-model="query" />
 <flex-slider class="carousel" slide="s in slides | filter:query">
```

...

When I'm typing some text into input console returns this error

Error: [$rootScope:infdig] 10 $digest() iterations reached. Aborting! Watchers fired in the last 5 iterations: ...

help please!

Answer (score 0):

The directive does not support filtering in this manner.

A work around is to setup a $watch on the `query` property. When it changes, update the slides array appropriately.